# paste contents from one file to another using linux

Tags: files

Consider if i have following:

```
cat /home/r1/f1.txt
sch1.t1
sch2.t2
sch2.t3
sch1.t4
```

also i have files

```
cat /home/r2/sch1.t1.txt
data

cat /home/r2/sch2.t2.txt
data1
```

i need to match from f1.txt the sch1.t1 with the files present in another directory (sch1.t1,.txt) and paste the following in f1.txt itself

o/p:

```
f1.txt

sch1.t1 data
sch2.t2 data1
```

i will have only f1.txt, and there might be many sch(1..n).t(1..n). each sch(1..n).t(1..n) are separate files with only one line of data.

if its a repeated question kindly guide me through it .

Tried code.

```
while read line
    do  
        paste f1.txt <(cut -f2 /home/r2/$line.txt) >> out_file.txt
        mv out_file.txt /home/r1/f1.txt
        
    done <  /home/r1/f1.txt
```

thanks fo r the reply.
updated question.
consider if the file is empty (Sch1.t4.txt). where to include the piece of code)

```
for file in /*.txt; 
    do 
        if [ ! -s $file ]; then 
            echo "NA"> $file; 
        fi; 
    done
```

o/p:

```
f1.txt

sch1.t1 data
sch2.t2 data1
sch1.t4 NA
```

Comment: The second (newly added) part of the question doesn't indicate what should happen to the results being generated for the `f1.txt` file. Rather you seem to want zero length files filled with the word `NA`. In such instances what, if anything, would you want in the `f1.txt` file?

Comment: i have shown the output of f1.txt file here.. if its empty file, add NA to the original file (sch1.t4.txt) and show NA in f1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I'd approach it is with a simple loop reading each entry from `f1.txt` and using that to build the results file. Once it's complete you can overwrite the original `f1.txt` file if that's what you want

```
#!/bin/sh
ctrl=/home/r1
base=/home/r2

# Loop across each entry
while IFS= read -r name
do
    # Derive filename
    file="$base/$name.txt"

    # Fix up if it doesn't already exist (or is zero length)
    [ ! -s "$file" ] && printf '%s\n' 'NA' >"$file"

    # Record what we've got
    printf '%s %s\n' "$name" "$(xargs <"$file")"

done <"$ctrl/f1.txt" >"$ctrl/f1.out"

# Replace the original file, saving it
[ ! -f "$ctrl/f1.old" ] && mv -f "$ctrl/f1.txt" "$ctrl/f1.old"
mv -f "$ctrl/f1.out" "$ctrl/f1.txt"
```

Comment: thank you so much :) Can you provide little bitof explanation would be great

Comment: i have a piece of code if sch1.t4.txt is empty.. how to include in this code?
for file in /*.txt; 
 do 
  if [ ! -s $file ]; then 
   echo "NA"> $file; 
  fi; 
 done

Comment: done . already..

Comment: it is not printing na in f1.txt file. Can you check? but the empty file has NA

Comment: @rose it works for me. What errors or other output do you get when you run it?

Comment: there is no error, but the second column is empty in main file for NA